# Is there a non-solvable number NOT divisible by $3\ $?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

Here

https://oeis.org/A056866

it is claimed that every non-solvable number is divisible by $4$ and either $3$ or $5$. However, I did not find a number in the list not divisible by $3$.

So, my question :

> Is there a non-solvable number NOT divisble by $3$ ?

Comment: I'm sure there's a smaller example, but the [Suzuki group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_simple_groups) with $q=8$ has order $8^2\times (8^2+1)\times (8-1)=29120$.

Comment: @lulu Since the Suzuki groups are the only finite simple groups with order not divisible by $3$, ${\rm Sz}(8)$ must be the smallest example.

Comment: @DerekHolt  Absolutely right.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encyclopedia of integer sequences has a list of possible criteria for a number being a non-solvable number, nicely laid out [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/10280/78224) on MathOverflow. One of these is 
$2^{2p}(2^{2p}+1)(2^p-1)$, p odd prime.

The [Suzuki groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_Lie_type#Suzuki.E2.80.93Ree_groups)  are the only finite non-abelian simple groups with order not divisible by 3, and they have order  $$2^{2(2n+1)}(2^{2(2n+1)} + 1)(2^{(2n+1)} −1)$$ which matches this criterion.

As mentioned by Derek Holt, it's also worth noting that since $2^{2(2n+1)}+1$ is divisible by $5$, it follows that all non-solvable groups whose order is not divisible by $3$ must be divisible by $5$.

Comment: Since $2^{2(2n+1)}+1$ is divisible by $5$, it follows that all non-solvable groups whose order is not divisible by $3$ must be divisible by $5$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Edited that info into my answer, hope you don't mind, thanks.

Comment: @DerekHolt are the non-solvable numbers completely classified ?

Comment: I don't know! It would reduce to two cases: groups divisible by $12$ but not by $5$, and groups divisible by $20$ but not by $3$.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "classified". A number of non-solvable if and only if it is a multiple of the order of a nonabelian simple groups, and the order of these is "known", so in this sense, such numbers are classified.

On the other hand, there are many concrete questions we cannot answer about such numbers. For example, I think it is unknown whether the set of orders of finite simple groups that are a product of exactly six primes is infinite or not.

Comment: Ron Solomon calls such problems "difficult and irrelevant obstacles" for understanding finite simple groups. See 

http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2001-38-03/S0273-0979-01-00909-0/S0273-0979-01-00909-0.pdf

and

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/67671/number-of-prime-factors-of-the-order-of-a-finite-non-abelian-simple-group